# An entire function which is onto

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that $\sin z - z$ is surjective, z$\in \mathbb C$

$\sin z - z$ is an entire function and hence by Little Picard its image can omit at most one complex number. I am unable to arrive at a contradiction from here on. Is there a way out! Please help.

Comment: Another approach could be using the definition of these functions.

Comment: @Emad And exactly how would you do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\sin(z) - z$ is odd, so if it omitted one non-zero point, it would omit two.

Comment: It seems to be huge overkill to use Picard for this simple function, but at the same time it's so damn elegant. A really cool proof!

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos A more elementary approach is to use the consequence of Cauchy's theorem that if $\sin(z) - z - a$ had no roots, then it's of the form $e^{g(z)}$ for $g(z)$ entire .  Then the real part of $g(z)$ is at most linear, so $g(z)$ is linear, which is obviously nonsense since we know what $\sin(z)$ is in terms of exponentials.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $f(z) = \sin(z) - z$ omits the value $a \in \Bbb C$. Then
$$
 f(z) = \sin(z  +2\pi) -(z+2\pi) + 2\pi = f(z+2\pi) + 2\pi
$$
also omits the value $a+2\pi$, contradicting Picard's theorem.

(And “Picard's Great Theorem” implies that $\sin(z)-z=a$ has infinitely many solutions for any $a \in \Bbb C$).

---

An alternative solution is possible with the [Hadamard factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#Hadamard_factorization_theorem). $\sin(z)-z-a$ has the order $1$. If it has no zeros then
$$
 \sin(z) = a+z+e^{cz+d}
$$
with complex constants $c, d \in \Bbb C$. But the right-hand side is unbounded for $z=x \in \Bbb R$, so this is not possible.

In the same way it can be shown that $\sin(z) - P(z)$ has infinitely many zeros for any polynomial $P$.